# Swift can't get `didUpdateLocations` to trigger

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have the following `Location` class, that I want to return the current location.  However, I can't get the current location.  I believe I've added all the correct PLIST items and added Core Location framework.  When I tap `getLocation`, the permissions disappears and I can't approve permission.

Debugger returns the following:

```
CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() true
location Services Enabled
locationManager.delegate <Shot_On_Goal.Location: 0x1c001f560>


@IBAction func getLocation(_ sender: Any) {

    let location = Location()
    location.getCurrentLocation()

}



import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class Location: NSObject {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    func getCurrentLocation() {

        print("class->Location->getCurrentLocation")

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            print("location Services Enabled")

            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        } else {

            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }

}  // class

extension Location: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

        print("class->Location->didFailWithError")

        print("Error to update location \(error)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        print("class->Location->didChangeAuthorization")

        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("notDetermined")
        case .restricted:
            print("restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("denied")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("authorizedAlways")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("authorizedWhenInUse")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        print("class->Location->didUpdateLocations")

        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }

} //extension
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this code:

```
let location = Location() // <-- oops
location.getCurrentLocation()
```

This Location instance needs to be a persistent retained object (e.g. a global or an instance property of some persistent view controller or app delegate). It can't be a local variable as you have it; it just vanishes before it can do any work.

Comment: See my example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift I do something quite similar to you, putting all the location stuff into a ManagerHolder class - but look at how I instantiate that class as an instance property of my root view controller. That's why my code works and yours doesn't.